# Bootstrap 4 navbar isn't responsive and stays opened when styled

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm having an issue with my navbar... After I style it with CSS it isn't very responsive and it stays opened on smaller screens.. Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark" id="big-bar">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-el">
              <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active flip" href="home.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link flip" href="mansion.html">Mansion</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link flip" href="#third-div">Sacrificial Grounds</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link flip" href="#fourth-div">Children of the Forest</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link flip" href="#fifth-div">About</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  background-color: black;
}

.navbar {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#navbar-el {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#navbar-el a {
  margin: 0 50px 0 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;

}

#navbar-el a:link {
}

#navbar-el a:visited {
}

#navbar-el a:hover {
    color: #ED8105;
}

#navbar-el a:active {
  color: #ED8105 !important;
}

#navbar-el a:focus{
  outline: none;
}
```

Codepen:https://codepen.io/Sarithan/pen/jvKaGa

Comment: One tip: Please have your code formatted when you post it. It will make it easier for people to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the margin from your anchor tags (set it to `margin: 0 auto;`, and use `justify-content: space-between;` on your `navbar-nav`. I also added `flex-grow: 1;` to the `navbar-nav`

I added this CSS:

```
.navbar-nav{
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Please check the codepen.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rZKEvq

Comment: The bad thing is that the button itself doesn't work :D

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
Change the ID of your navbar-collapse to the correct ID:
`<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">`

See the pen for a working version. The ID of your `.navbar-collapse` needs to be the same of the `data-target` value.

Answer (score 0):

It stays open because you have `display:flex` in the extra CSS...

```
#navbar-el {
  display:flex
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Remove the `display:flex'. Also make sure you have the correct target for the toggler.

https://www.codeply.com/go/5NWAu5Zz1X

Comment: What about the fact that it doesn't shrink with the page? I know it's because of the margin.. but I couldn't fix it even with media queries..

Answer (score 0):

use navbar-expand-lg

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" id="big-bar">
```

A standard navigation bar is created with the .navbar class, followed by a responsive collapsing class: .navbar-expand-xl|lg|md|sm (stacks the navbar vertically on extra large, large, medium or small screens).

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp